# How To Get Data by Name Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im Beginer in Codeigniter
I have table

table_a :

[image]

I want create detail data only about 'STEVE' like :

[image]

but I can't get all data by NAME.Only data By ID.

This last try code in My Model:

```
public function detail($id){
$where = array('id' => $id);
$name = 'name', $name;
$data['sales'] = $this->people->detail($where,'table_a')->row();
$data['saless'] = $this->people->getdatabyname($name);
$this->template->display('test/detail',$data);
```

}

This My Controller :

```
   function detail($where,$table){
    return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
  }
  function getdatabyname($name){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_a');
    $this->db->where('table_a.name', $name);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```

Please Help

Comment: you should add a "user_ID" for each person (in table_a). This user_ID could come from another table e.g. "users". Whenever you insert a new row in table_a you would insert as well that user_ID. Then you can query easily for that user_ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you have $id is table_a primary key id then you can get by this:
//controller
function detail($id){
$data=array();
$this->load->model('model_name');
$table_a_data= $this->model_name->get_table_a_by_id($id);
$data['steve']=$this->model_name->get_steve_by_name($table_a_data->name);
$this->template->display('test/detail',$data);
  }

//model
function get_table_a_by_id($id){
return $this->db->where('id',$id)->get()->row_array();
}
function get_steve_by_name($name){
return $this->db->where('name',$name)->get()->result_array();
}

//if you don't have id then use join to get data
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. but i got error 'A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'